# What does the values in column clazz (osm2po) mean?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, java, osm2po

I have a given table in postgreSQL with OSM data which is used for routing purposes in Java with PGRouting. There exist two columns which I don't understand. They belong to osm2po. They are labeled with "flags" and "clazz". I know, that flags describe the kind of road. It means, whether it is driveable by car, bike,... The problem now is, that I do not understand the meanings of the values in the column clazz. I just know that they also describe the road type. Can anybody explain, what the values like 12, 15, 31,... mean? Does a documentation exist where the meaning of the values is written down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file osm2po.config, which can be obtained from the downloads tab on the osm2po page, contains a table with four column, defined as:

> 1) concurrent order
>
> 2) class (1-127)
>
> 3) default speed in kmh
>
> 4) allowed transportation type (optional) - since v4.5.30

And here are some sample rows, which I think explain where the 12, 51, etc, you are seeing comes from (in the second column).

```
wtr.tag.highway.motorway =       1, 11, 120, car
wtr.tag.highway.motorway_link =  1, 12, 30,  car
wtr.tag.highway.service =        1, 51, 5,   car|bike
wtr.tag.highway.living_street =  1, 63, 7,   car|bike|foot
```

It does say that the class can be in the range 1-127, and there are only 23 different values in that config table, so I trust that covers all the ones you are seeing?

Following comment from OP, here are the [the official osm highway docs](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The config file contains all possible values of classes. Each value can be assigned to a specific highway type. The descriptions of every type can be found in the OSM wiki (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Key:highway). Thanks, your answer helped a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome. I added your link to the question, but in English, as my German is a bit rusty :D

Answer (score 3):

As for the flags, I just wrote up a little explanation [here](http://natewessel.com/2016/03/osm2pos-flag-field-explained/). I wish I would have figured the flags out a while ago! Very useful, and a clever encoding.

Comment: This link is dead. This answer is no longer useful, unfortunately.

Comment: Ideally add the explanation from your link to your answer. This will improve your answer and prevent having the same problem again in the future. Link-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

From the osm2po.config file:

```
road type       clazz
motorway        11
motorway_link   12
trunk           13
trunk_link      14
primary         15
primary_link    16
secondary       21
secondary_link  22
tertiary        31
tertiary_link   32
residential     41
road            42
unclassified    43
```