# Meaning of OSM file columns

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

I imported an OSM file of San Francisco and I get this dataset:

[image]

Can any one help me to understand the meaning of these columns:

- km/h: is this the limit speed or the average speed of each road?
- flags
- clazz

Comment: I added the *osm2po* tag, that's crucial information. the *osm2po.config* file is the main pool for information on those columns; *kmh* is a hard-coded average based on german/european traffic assumptions (I guess), the other fields are encoded road types: *flag* denotes the road usage (car, bicylce, etc.), *clazz* the road type. check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116701/what-does-the-values-in-column-clazz-osm2po-mean) answer for more details. as I said in your other question, you can override the average speed values with the OSM  *maxspeed* tag.

Comment: @ThingumaBob thank you for your answers, ok i will try to use the max speed tag.

Answer (score 3):

These columns are created by osm2po based on your osm2po.config file. These specific columns and values are *not* contained in OSM! They are constructed based on certain rules that osm2po assumes and that are found in the osm2po.config file.

Some of these values are explained at [What does the values in column clazz (osm2po) mean?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/116701/23837).

Note that osm2po is a closed source project. It looks like there is no good documentation available. For further questions try to contact the author or switch to a different tool.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. I will try to contact the author.

Answer (score 2):

The tags `km\h, flags, clazz` are very unique. [Taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=clazz) doesnot show any record of them, so most probably they were used by people who had no idea about correct tagging techniques. It would be impossible to find their real meaning unless we ask the original uploader. If it's irrelevant to you, you can delete those columns.

Comment: Well, I’m using a formula that needs the average speed of roads as input so i would like to know the meaning of these columns especially kmh if it means the average speed or the limit speed

Comment: @Reem I'm just guessing, but that doesn't look like speed limit to me. Most US Highways have 65 mph as a speed limit, rarely 70 mph segments (I just googled, don't quote me on that). Both are below 120kmh (104.6kmh and 112.6kmh respectively). Maybe it's the average speed, rounded up? But even that seems strange due to the heavy rounding going on there.

Comment: @Iridium  thank you for answering, this is really what i think, that the column kmh mean the average speed but i can't confirm also.

Comment: just to clear things up; the above tag/column setup is the result of a *osm2po* import and has several road tags/types encoded in those columns/values. the *osm2po.config* file has more detail, or the post I linked in my comment above.

Comment: @ThingumaBob Thank you for your clear and helpful explanations.

Answer (score 1):

OSM doesnot have data classified into layers, all the data is in one layer. The feature identify themselves as tags(`in form of key = value pairs`) e.g. `amenity = bank` , `highway = motorway`.

When OSM file is imported all data come in one layer and the **keys** become **columns** and **value** becomes the **values**. Since all columns become keys there will be many unnecessary and un-understandable columns. Most of the tags are defined [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i would like to know the meaning of flags=3 for example, or the clazz=41, and if the column kmh means the max speed of roads or it's the average speed ?

Comment: see the next answer